# Programmatically Find all operating systems installed on a computer using Powershell or Command Prompt

Tags: powershell, command-line, operating-system, windows-10, bcdedit

I need to programmatically verify that only Windows 10 is installed on a computer.

This information is manually available in Windows 10 by navigating to 
Advanced System Settings >> Advanced Tab >> Settings in Startup and Recovery Section >> Opening the drop down menu "Default operating system

Perhaps there is a way using the BCDedit command line tool.

Comment: Sounds interesting. However, this is a programmer's Q&A site, not a "I need someone to research a solution for me" site.

Comment: `bcdedit /enum` ?

Comment: Are you sure that's how to find this info? I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu, and I only see Windows 10 in that drop-down list.

Comment: In powershell, there are several ways to view storage partitions, Get-Volume, Get-Partition, Get-Disk. Maybe one of these has information about the operating system it is connected with.

Comment: @glennjackman The badmitten's GUI method is getting the information from the Windows boot loader. But if another is put in front like Grub or Lilo that information would not be available.

Comment: It would answer my question to explain how to access this information from the Windows boot loader programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much concerning having multiple operating systems, but if you want a PowerShell answer to view the current windows OS...

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
```

^ This will return some general info about the OS

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | select *
```

^ This will select all the properties available from the Win32_OperatingSystem class that has a fair amount of information to look through

```
(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
```

^ This will get the name of the specific OS installed

Comment: Get-wmiobject also has the     `-computername` switch to get info for remote machines